# How to reach openapi interface for minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

According to [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/), you can ping an http endpoint for a K8s cluster to operate it instead of using e.g. `kubectl`. It also says that there is an openApi interface available at `/openapi/v2`. I'm running minikube on MacOS and would like to check it out. Does anyone know if that is possible?

I tried:

```
minikube list service # Shows 'kubernetes' as a name
minikube list kubernetes
```

... which opens the browser to `127.0.0.1:51377`. However, when I try going to `https://127.0.0.1:51377/openapi/v2` I get the message:

```
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/openapi/v2\"",
"reason": "Forbidden",
"details": {},
"code": 403
}
```

... suggesting that I need some sort of authorization solution. Suggestions?

Comment: Does your cluster has RBAC enabled?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor No

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
# Proxy minikube to localhost on arbitrary port:
kubectl proxy --port=12345

# Now swagger.json is available at localhost:12345/openapi/v2
# Save to /tmp/temp/json and serve with e.g. docker swagger-ui container
curl localhost:12345/openapi/v2 > /tmp/temp.json
docker run -it -p 9999:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/var/specs/temp.json -v /tmp/temp.json:/var/specs/temp.json swaggerapi/swagger-ui

# Open browser to localhost:9999
```